# QWebView DOM структура

Tags: qt, c++

Есть ли встроенные средства для отладки `QWebView`? Интересует просмотр DOM структуры.

Если встроенных нет, подскажите, как отобразить DOM структуру `QWebView` в `QTreeView`?

Еще есть вопрос: `QWebView` Как добавить элемент после к примеру `#id1`?

Answer (score 2):

Для просмотра и редактирования DOM используйте `QWebInspector`. Он подключается к `QWebPage`. Также незабудьте разрешить использование инструментария разработчика установкой соответствующего флага в `QWebSettings`:

```
my_page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);
```